# How do you find the bounds of your program memory/segmentation from the system in C/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, segment

How do you find the bounds of your program memory/segmentation from the system in C/Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Dogbert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490026/1475978) lets you find out and modify (if permitted) the process *limits*.

If you want to know how a process uses its virtual address space -- that is, which addresses are used and for what purpose --, examine the `/proc/PID/maps` or `/proc/PID/smaps` pseudofiles. The format and fields are described in the [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page.

Remember that those are pseudofiles provided directly by the kernel (they look like files, but are generated by the kernel as needed), and therefore always use the C/POSIX locale (`LC_ALL=C LANG=C`). The existing format should not change, but new fields might be added.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`getrlimit` and `setrlimit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) in C on *NIX systems to get/set things like:

- Stack size
- Heap size
- Virtual address space